# How datanode path is created in hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Here is my sample snippet which I use to write file to `hdfs`

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Progressable;

public class WriteFileToHDFS {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException 
   {
      System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "/");   
      System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "hdfs");  

      //1. Get the instance of COnfiguration
      Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

      //2. Create an InputStream to read the data from local file
      InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/Users/rabbit/Research/hadoop/sample_files/TAO.mp4"));  

      //3. Get the HDFS instance
      FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://192.168.143.150:9000"), configuration);  

      //4. Open a OutputStream to write the data, this can be obtained from the FileSytem
      OutputStream outputStream = hdfs.create(new Path("hdfs://192.168.143.150:9000/filestore/TAO.mp4"),   
      new Progressable() {  
              @Override
              public void progress() {
                System.out.println("....");
              }
        });
      try
      {
        IOUtils.copyBytes(inputStream, outputStream, 4096, false); 
      }
      finally
      {
        IOUtils.closeStream(inputStream);
        IOUtils.closeStream(outputStream);
      } 
  }
}
```

I expect this to be written as `/data/hadoop-data/dn/current/blk_1073741869` instead it is written as `/data/hadoop-data/dn/current/BP-1308070615-172.22.131.23-1533215887051/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741869`. I do not understand where `BP-1308070615-172.22.131.23-1533215887051/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0` - this path got generated?

How the path structure is defined while writing to data node in hadoop?

Comment: Based on what are you expecting only `current/blk_1073741869`? Where did you get that number?

Comment: That is the block id which is there in fsimage.@cricket_007

Comment: Sure, but I'm asking how you would expect that number without first going to look at the Fsimage? (based on the code given)

Comment: BTW, you can directly invoke the equivalent `hdfs dfs put` command using the `Put` class http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/shell/CopyCommands.java?view=markup#l216

Comment: In any case, I feel like your question is answered here https://hortonworks.com/blog/hdfs-metadata-directories-explained/

Comment: Thanks for sharing @cricket_007 :) Got my answer there :)

Comment: It is a very interesting question. Given you have got an answer, would be great if you can share the answer :)

Comment: Yeah sure @dbustosp. I'll post it as an answer soon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***BP*** stands for "Block Pool", a collection of blocks which are belonging to a single HDFS namespace.

The next part is ***1308070615***, is a random generated integer.

The IP address ***172.22.131.23*** is the address of the NameNode that originally created the block pool.

The last part ***1533215887051*** is the creation time of the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The BP stands for "block pool", a collection of blocks belonging to a single HDFS namespace.

This is how hdfs manages data blocks, you can refer to this link to know every thing about it:

https://hortonworks.com/blog/hdfs-metadata-directories-explained/